# How to select a entire row and highlight in different color in google sheet using script editor?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to use code below to find blank values in column 6 and highlight the entire row in yellow:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ActiveSheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  for (i=2;i<=ActiveSheet.getLastRow();i++){
    var day = ActiveSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    if (day == ''){
      ActiveSheet.getRange('i').setBackground('#ffff00');
    }
}
}
```

However this doesn't work. Do anybody know how to select row "i" and highlight it? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: possible to show a demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your code just needs a slight modification:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ActiveSheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  for (i=2;i<=ActiveSheet.getLastRow();i++){
    var day = ActiveSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    if (day == ''){
      ActiveSheet.getRange(i,1,1,ActiveSheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground('#ffff00');
    }
  }
}
```

> Explanation:

The range should be defined as

[getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)